# How to create indexer for custom table

Tags: magento2, indexing, indexer

I want to create an indexer for my custom EAV entity (for learning purposes only).
I have the following tables:

```
custom_employee_entity
custom_employee_entity_datetime
custom_employee_entity_decimal
custom_employee_entity_int
custom_employee_entity_text
custom_employee_entity_varchar
```

In the table custom_employee_entity I have column `first_name` and for example, in the table custom_employee_entity_decimal I have the value of EAV attribute `salary`. So what I want is to create an indexer that will save (On update or by Schedule) employee names and salaries in some table so then I will be able to show it on the frontend, I know it's not useful but as I said I just want to learn and understand how to implement something like this. Thanks for any help)

Answer (score 0):

Magento official document has a document very details for creating a custom indexer, let's take a look and try to apply it to your custom module:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/custom-indexer/

If you found anything does not clear or you had any issues, create a new question for that, and we'll help.